# .htaccess: SetEnvIf Host не работает для поддоменов

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Мне нужно устанавливать различные переменные Env для различных поддоменов. Например, domain/subdomain1 MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en, а domain/subdomain2 MAGE_RUN_CODE=global

Работает такой вариант:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*mydomain.net.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```

Такой вариант не работает:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*mydomain.net/ahava-m1-mobile.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевое слово **HOST** используется для http host заголовков типа **example.com** . Чтобы проверить url, содержит ли он какой-то поддомен (например, **/ahava-m1-mobile**), нужно проверять переменную Request-uri.

```
SetEnvIF request_uri ^/ahava-m1-mobile MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```